# jQuery - Unable to remove checked attribute from checkboxes

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, reset

I have a form generated with the answer of an Ajax request to a PHP page communicating with my database.

When I click on the `submit` button, I gather through jQuery for the content of the different form inputs (text,checkbox,textarea,...) in simple arrays to send them back to the database.

Now I want to reset the `form` after the submission.
I failed to use `myForm.reset()` to clear everything (it did nothing) even with all the methods I found on StackOverflow and the internet in general. So I decided to code the clear process myself.

**To the main problem** : I gather the values of the checked checkboxes with :

```
var complement0=[];
complement0.push($("input[name=foo]:checked").map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get());
```

And then try to uncheck the checkboxes. Here are the ways I tried to do it without success :

```
$("input[name=foo]:checked").each(function() {
  $(this).removeAttr('checked');
});

$("input[name=foo]:checked").map(function() {
  return this;
}).removeAttr('checked');

$("input[name=prsFmtLng]:checked").attr('checked',false);

$("input[name=prsFmtLng]:checked").removeAttr('checked');
```

Since it looks like to be simple when other people talk about this: either I don't understand what I am doing or I am just missing something.

Any help is welcomed.

**The answer :**

```
    $("input[name=foo]:checked").map(function() {
        $(this).prop('checked',false);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`checked` is a property.

Use :

```
.prop('checked',false);
```

;)

Comment: While you answered here I found out thanks to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr/5876747#5876747
Thank you anyway =)

Comment: Had to wait 1min before I could accept it. I edited my question to add the answer. I don't if I should just delete it since I had to search for a while before finding that simple answer. Should I ?

Comment: Your choice! Do you think your question may help future reader is the question to ask yourself. ;)

Comment: Then I'll leave it because many other questions related to checked checkboxes doesn't talk about this detail.
Thank you again.

Comment: Was a pleasure ;)